# New red popup boxes are inconvenient

Tags: discussion, feature-request, popups

Previously in order to close the popup window at SO you needed to click at any place of the popup. It was *fast*, *easy* and *convenient*.

Now in the new design I need to search for `X` button to do that, otherwise the popup will be opened constantly. It irritates me! Moreover, the "Close" button merges with the background, and I'm sure the people with weak eyesight will support me.

[image]

I think it is better to get rid of "Close" buttons and get back to previous functionality.

Comment: Gah, got that annoying popup when posting that dup vote :-(((((

Comment: @Mat Ah, damn! I haven't found that question in search. *Always* when you ask something at Meta, someone has already asked it.